# Switch data-descritpion direction from ltr to rtl

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button

I have a button with a data-descritpion that gets displayed to the user in my wordpress site. I am wondering how I can go about switching the direction of the text from Left-to-Right to Right-to-Left as the content will be in Hebrew.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue; see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

Comment: @WillParky93 That would be correct except its in a data-description field within the `a` tag. Therefore the CSS properties have no effect